# Sequelize - Add new row to table and to associate table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize ORM with MySql and currently run up against problem with creating new entry in table and in associate table.
    My models:
     Articles

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Articles = sequelize.define('articles', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        author: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        intro: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        article: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        cd: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        }
    }, {
        createdAt: 'cd',
        updatedAt: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                this.belongsToMany(models.comments, {
                    through: 'commented_articles'
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return Articles;
};

Comments:

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Comments = sequelize.define('comments', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        id_parent: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: null
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: null
        },
        nick: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        comment: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        plus: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: null,
            validate: {
                isInt: {
                    msg: "Must be an integer number."
                }
            }
        },
        minus: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: null,
            validate: {
                isInt: {
                    msg: "Must be an integer number."
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        createdAt: 'cd',
        updatedAt: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                this.belongsToMany(models.articles, {
                    through: 'commented_articles'
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return Comments;
};

I want to add new comment to article, so probably my routing would look like

module.exports = function (app) {
    var articles = require('./../apiMethods/articlesMethods');
    app.post('/articles/:id/comments', articles.getSingleArticle);
};

I was trying to use addComment (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/)

var models = require('../models'),
    MyModel = require('../supportMethods/modelMethods'),
    supportModel = new MyModel(models.articles);

module.exports = (function () {
    return {
        setArticle: function (req, res) {
            models.articles.addComments(models.comments, {
                user_id: req.body.user_id,
                nick: req.body.nick,
                title: req.body.title,
                comment: req.body.comment
            })
        }
    };
})();
The "commented_articles" is obviously automaticaly generated by squelize and contains article_id, comment_id and cd (row update timestamp).
```

What I want to achive is to add comments to appropriate article and in the same time adding new cell in the "commented_articles". The "comments" table contains comments to articles and to pictures (there is also a "commented_images" table).
I was trying to use addComments method but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
    Thanks

Comment: I've solved my problem:

Answer (score 3):

I've solved my problem. Dirty version is:

```
addNewCommentToArticle: function (req, res) {
    var id_parent = req.body.id_parent,
        user_id = req.body.user_id,
        nick = req.body.nick,
        title = req.body.title,
        comment = req.body.comment;
    models.articles.findByPrimary(req.params.id)
        .then(function (createdArticle) {
            models.comments.create({
                id_parent: id_parent,
                user_id: user_id,
                nick: nick.trim(),
                title: title.trim(),
                comment: comment.trim()
            }).then(function (newComment) {
                createdArticle.addComments(newComment)
                    .then(function () {
                        res.json(newComment);
                    })
                    .catch(function (e) {
                        res.json(e);
                    });
            })
     });
 }
```

Hoping someone find it useful.